# Ghc mod: change default target

Tags: haskell, ghc-mod

Is there a way to change ghc-mod's target?

I have a cabal file with two sections: a library target, and a tests target. Ghc detects modules for packages in the library target correctly.

However, if I add a package only to the tests target (such as QuickCheck), it will flag the "import" as an error. Any workarounds for that?

Comment: perhaps you could post the (relevant bits of) your `.cabal` file?